Spherical pendulum newtonian

I want to solve the equation of motion of mass $m$ in a Newtonian way.
I don't know what kind of force makes $φ$ directional motion.
In addition, if I solve this problem with Newton's equation of motion, I have no idea how to set the equation.
In my opinion, the only torque for φ seems to be gravity.
Could you help me please?

There's nothing "spherical" here

"In my opinion" There is nothing to do with opinion here. It is either correct or wrong.

If you have no initial velocity perpendicular to the plane of your picture you will not have motion in phi direction, only just a normal pendulum, so you have to give it a push in phi direction at the beginning.
